# Protocol.UndefinedError in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to convert database new environment.

I executed `phx.gen.json` then created related models.
There are tables already in database. I think I don't need `ecto migration` for database.

However I had following error, when I access json url path.
It seems to have success to database and get data. Because I see `QUERY OK`.

```
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for nil of type Atom. This protocol is implemented for the following type(s): Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Stream, DBConnection.Stream, DBConnection.PrepareStream, HashSet, Range, Map, Function, List, Stream, Date.Range, HashDict, GenEvent.Stream, MapSet, File.Stream, IO.Stream
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1: Enumerable.impl_for!/1
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:141: Enumerable.reduce/3
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:3023: Enum.map/2
        (falcons) lib/falcons_web/views/member_view.ex:6: FalconsWeb.MemberView.render/2
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/view.ex:410: Phoenix.View.render_to_iodata/3
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/controller.ex:729: Phoenix.Controller.__put_render__/5
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/controller.ex:746: Phoenix.Controller.instrument_render_and_send/4
        (falcons) lib/falcons_web/controllers/member_controller.ex:1: FalconsWeb.MemberController.action/2
        (falcons) lib/falcons_web/controllers/member_controller.ex:1: FalconsWeb.MemberController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:288: Phoenix.Router.__call__/2
        (falcons) lib/falcons_web/endpoint.ex:1: FalconsWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
        (falcons) lib/plug/debugger.ex:122: FalconsWeb.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (falcons) lib/falcons_web/endpoint.ex:1: FalconsWeb.Endpoint.call/2
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy2_handler.ex:42: Phoenix.Endpoint.Cowboy2Handler.init/4
        (cowboy) /Users/tajima/Works/Falcons/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_handler.erl:41: :cowboy_handler.execute/2
        (cowboy) /Users/tajima/Works/Falcons/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:320: :cowboy_stream_h.execute/3
        (cowboy) /Users/tajima/Works/Falcons/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:302: :cowboy_stream_h.request_process/3
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

What is wrong with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by mismatch of code.
I copyed from the others method.
There are few difference. `members: members` or else.

contraller

```
  def login(conn, %{"email" => email, "passwd" => passwd}) do
    member = Scoresheet.login(email, passwd)
    render(conn, "login.json", member: member)
  end
```

View

```
  def login(email, passwd) do
    Repo.get_by(Member, email: email, password_digest: passwd)
  end
```

I should have noticed very carefully.
Thanks.